# User cookie set to root path, but I still can't see it when using ngCookies

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies, web, spring-security

So I have a Backend that has a login method to handle our authentication. In this login I set the cookie that contains the username to the root path, so it can accessed by everything.

```
RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/login", headers = "Accept=application/json")
public @ResponseBody HttpServletResponse login(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    // toLog(Level.INFO, "Logging user in.");
    String referingURL = request.getHeader("referer");
    _LOG.debug("Referer: " + referingURL);
    try {
        String user = "123456789";
        user = SecurityUtils.getCurrentUsername();
        Cookie userCookie = new Cookie("USERNAME", user);
        userCookie.setSecure(true);
        userCookie.setDomain(referingURL);
        userCookie.setPath("/");
        response.addCookie(userCookie);
        _LOG.debug("Cookie Path: " + userCookie.getPath());
        response.sendRedirect(referingURL);
        return response;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // toLog(Level.ERROR, "Error logging user in", e);
        throw new ResourceNotFoundException(e);
    }
}
```

On the Angular side, I'm using ngCookies for my cookie retrieval and storage. The Angular version is 1.4.6, for reference.

When I use ngCookies, I do a

```
$cookies.put('USERNAME', ' ', { path: '/', domain: 'https://example.com', secure: true }
```

But when I login and have a `console.log($cookies.getAll()` or a `console.log($cookies.get('USERNAME)` I get either an object with a USERNAME with no value, or an undefined, or an empty object.

What am I doing wrong with my ngCookies or where I'm setting that cookie path?

Comment: is back end on different domain or port?

Comment: 1. do you excess your frontend over a https connection? otherwise no cookie will be available

Comment: 2. you don't need to store the cookie manually on client side. angular takes care of it. take a look in the developer tools of your browser and see what cookies are set

Comment: @charlietfl When it's hosted, domain is https://node.dev.com/app, backend is https://node.dev.com:8082/app

Comment: @bopa - Locally I think I'll have to configure my gulp server to do an HTTPS connection, but when it's hosted it's all HTTPS. I also do see the cookies set in my browser.

Comment: try using `withCredentials` header in `$http`